# Determine whether the following arguments are correct or incorrect

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> For the sequence $a_j=(\frac{cos(j)}{j},\frac{sin(j)}{j})$, determine whether the following arguments are correct or incorrect:
>
> $1.$ The sequence converges to $(0,0)$ because it all of its subsequences converges to $(0,0)$.
>
> $2.$ The sequence converges to $(0,0)$ because every open ball $B(0;r)$ contains infinitely many points from the sequence.
>
> $3.$ The sequence converges to $(0,0)$ because the sequence of real numbers ${|a_j|}$ converges to $0$.
>
> $4.$ The sequence converges to $(0,0)$ because it has a subsequence that converges to $(0,0)$.
>
> $5.$ The sequence converges because it is contained in the compact set $\overline{B}(0;1)$.
>
> $6.$ The sequence doesn't converge because it contains infinitely many points with $x>0$ and infinitely many points with $x<0$.
>
> $7.$ The sequence converges to $(0,0)$ because the sequence of distances between consecutive terms $\{|a_{j+1}−a_j|\}$ converges to $0$.

---

[image]

This is graph for $a_j$

Already know $a_j$ converges to $(0,0)$, that $6$ must be incorrect

Basicly, this is asking why $a_j$ is convergent.

And there might be more than one in $\{1-7\}\backslash\{6.\}$ are correct.

Actually I have no idea$\dots$which of them are correct $?$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, asking others to solve your homework problems is an academic offence. If you have questions about these and other problems you have posted on MSE, you are welcome to come to my office hours or our help centres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2), 4), 5),6) and 7) are false. 1) and 3) are correct.